# Is there a way to quickly view which heists I have done and on which difficulties?

Tags: payday-2

Is there a way to check which heists I have already done and on which difficulties easily? I know I can go check each individual heist to see which ones, what difficulties, and how many times, but I am looking for a quicker way.

Update: I would prefer if I didn't have to use a mod.

Comment: From what I remember the only way was checking each individually in the contract broker.

Comment: Yep as Timmy said the only way to check without a mod is individually with the contract broker

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you're playing this via PC and Steam.

In the FBI Files (fbi.overkillsoftware.com, or accessible in-game from the main menu), you can check which heists you've completed by looking at your own profile and clicking the "view suspect's statistics" button.

Another way to check which heists you've completed is to check your achievements. This is however not as good as the FBI files, as the FBI files shows what you've completed in an easier to read format.

Do note both of these ways only show if you've beaten heists on Mayhem difficulty or above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing on PC then the PocoHud mod will, among other things, show you how many times you have attempted and succeeded for each heist at each difficulty level.

Comment: I am trying to see if I can see it without a mod.

Comment: Might be a way of checking your profile through the FBI files and seeing what stats it offers you, but it's not a feature I really bother with.